# Modules and numpy.random seeds

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have two modules, the first of which is:

```
# module.py

import numpy
import myrandom

class A():
    def __init__(self,n1,n2):
        A.rng_set1 = myrandom.generate_random(n1)
        A.rng_set2 = myrandom.generate_random(n2)
        A.data = np.concatenate((A.rng_set1,A.rng_set2))
```

The module `myrandom` is something like:

```
# myrandom.py

import numpy as np

def generate_random(n):
    return np.random.rand(n)
```

Given a seed I want `A.data` to be predictable. I don't want `rng_set1` and `rng_set2` to share the same numbers if `n1` equals `n2`. I don't understand how to seed this thing.

I've tried putting `np.random.seed(constant)` into `generate_random`, into `A`'s init, at `module.py` top level and before `import module.py`. I can't seem to get the desired result.

How am i supposed to do this? Thank you.

---

EDIT:

An oversight from me was causing the unpredictable behaviour. Please see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You could change `myrandom.py` to:

```
# myrandom.py

import numpy as np

def generate_random(n):
    np.random.seed(n)
    return np.random.rand(n)
```

This makes the `seed` replicable and changes the output for different inputs.

Better:

```
def generate_random(n):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=n)
    return rng.random.rand(n)
```

Comment: note that this modifies global state.  it will therefore cause any other users of the numpy's RNG to see the same deterministic behaviour, i.e. code like this will probably have unintended consequences!

Comment: @SamMason Thanks, that's a good point. I will add another version that should be saver.

Comment: @Timus thank you. I also find this kind of dangerous. I would not seed based on the `generate_random` argument. The problem I was encountering was explained with a simple oversight. Please see answer below.

Comment: @Timus that looks much safer!  note that `rng.random(n)` might be more intuitive

Answer (score 2):

[Based on numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html?highlight=seed#numpy.random.seed) `numpy.random.rand()` is a legacy function. Numpy suggests constructing a [Generator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.Generator) with a seed, that can be used to generate numbers deterministically. As a convenience function, `numpy.random.default_rng()` can be used to create to simply create a generator:

```
from numpy import random

# seed can be a number that will ensure deterministic behaviour
generator_1 = random.default_rng(seed=1)
generator_1.integers(10, size=10)
# array([4, 5, 7, 9, 0, 1, 8, 9, 2, 3])

generator_2 = random.default_rng(seed=1)
generator_2.integers(10, size=10)
# array([4, 5, 7, 9, 0, 1, 8, 9, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an oversight here. The unpredictable behaviour I was encountering was due to mixing  `numpy.random` and python's `random` library. Having only `numpy.random` to act within `generate_random` results in the expected behaviour when `np.random.seed()` is called before importing `module` or at top level of `module` or `myrandom`. Thank you all my friends for your time and helpfulness.